# How to check cluster name, execution time of dataproc jobs via gcloud command

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

We need to investigate dataproc jobs ran on particular date.
While running command -

```
gcloud dataproc jobs list --region=<region_name>
```

It helps to get below output format -

```
JOB_ID   TYPE    STATUS
```

where TYPE could be spark/hive and STATUS could be DONE/ERROR

is there any way to check job execution time and cluster name as well ?

Comment: I think [`projects.regions.jobs.list`](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.jobs/list) backs the `gcloud dataproc jobs list` command. You can confirm this by adding `--log-http` to the `gcloud dataproc jobs list` command. The response body for the command is defined [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.jobs/list#response-body) and is a slice of [`Job`](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.jobs#Job).

Comment: `Job` includes [`JobPlacement`](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.jobs#JobPlacement) which should give cluster details for each job. There's a lengthy list of other properties that **may** (I don't know) include what you need. If you can find it, then you can access it from `gcloud dataproc jobs list` by appending e.g. `--format=yaml` and extracting the fields you need.

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with it, `gcloud` has extensive filtering and formatting functionality. IMO, this is poorly documented e.g. see [gcloud topic formats](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/formats) but it is exhaustive and you can probably do what you need. Alternatively, pump the output from `gcloud ... --format=json` into a tool like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and process it using that.

Comment: Thanks, gcloud ... --format=json helped me to get exact feature helpful for my anaysis

Comment: I'm pleased to hear it!